# htaccess rewrite specific slug to specific page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm currently working on building a simple CMS, and I want to rewrite specific slugs (like /setup, and /admin) to their respective pages, while allowing the htaccess to rewrite all the rest of the requests to my serving page.

Here is what I have in my .htaccess right now:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /

# Rewrite the setup slug to the setup page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/setup$
RewriteRule ^/setup$ /setup.php [L,R=301]

# Rewrite all other URL's to the keyhole that translates them
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ keyhole.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Currently, the redirect works for all other URLs. It captures each of them and then sends them on to keyhole.php. However, when I try to access `http://localhost/basic-cms/setup` it redirects me to `http://localhost/var/www/basic-cms/setup.php`.

Also, which I thought was strange, if I try to go to `http://localhost/basic-cms/setup.php` then it takes me to `http://localhost/setup.php`.

Also, when I uncomment the RewriteBase I still have the same problem, and then it breaks my other all-encompassing rewrite line.

**EDIT:**

I took the information provided from the answer given, and have a new .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite the setup slug to the setup page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^setup$
RewriteRule ^setup$ setup.php [L]

# Rewrite all URL's to the keyhole that translates them
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ basic-cms/keyhole.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However, while I no longer get strange redirects off the setup redirect, it doesn't seem to take setup to setup.php still. It acts as though it has skipped the RewriteCond that checks for ^setup$. I'm wondering if it has something to do with my newly established RewriteBase...

**Final Edit:**

Okay, after chewing on it a bit longer, I figured out where I went wrong. It was the condition that I messed up, because I had added the RewriteBase to the equation. So, for the record, here is the working .htaccess that allows me to redirect all slugs to keyhole.php, EXCEPT the setup slug, which will go directly to setup.php:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite the setup slug to the setup page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/basic-cms/setup$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ basic-cms/setup.php [L]

# Rewrite all URL's to the keyhole that translates them
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ basic-cms/keyhole.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Obviously, since I'm building on a local Apache instance, and I haven't set up a virtual host, this htaccess file will be trimmed a little when I move it to a real URL, so it doesn't include the "basic-cms" parts of the paths, since that directory will inevitably by the root directory on a live web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a internal redirect however on your rule you have **`R=301`** remove that and leave only **`[L]`**

You may also want to add to your keyhole.php rule the following conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

To avoid it from redirecting existent pages or directories to itself but that depends on how you will work your CMS.

From a CMS, WordPress base `.htaccess` note how they use the above:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: This helped a lot thanks! Now it seems as though it is skipping the RewriteCond for ^setup$ entirely though now. I think it might just be the way I have the condition laid out. If I figure it out before you have a chance to reply, I'll add an edit to describe my error, and mark this as the answer.

Comment: found it. I had just messed up my condition. Everything works great now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @SamHuckaby glad you figure it out and that my post was of help